# Is a List of IQueryable not by reference? (linq to sql)

Tags: c#, linq

if we take an easy example first to see my point (just an ordinary List)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Olle = new List<string>();

        Olle.Add("Niklas");
        Olle.Add("Peter");
        Olle.Add("Tobias");

        RemoveFirst(Olle);

        MessageBox.Show(Olle.Count().ToString()); 

    }
    private void RemoveFirst(List<string> O)
    {
        O.Remove(O.First());  
    }
```

> The message box will show 2 be because the list is by reference !

I expected the same behavior for a list of IQueryable or IEnumerable snare,
(Linq to Sql)
but to my surprise it became a value variable, can someone explain this to me?
ie. after passing a method and came back, the method was to filter the list !
According to the example below:

```
    private void foo(int therecord)
    {
      var FooList = DataContext.MyTable.Where
                    (l => l.ID == therecord).OrderBy(l => l.FirstName).ToList();

       //Lets say the result is 15 records. 
        MessageBox.Show(FooList.Count().ToString());

       //filter method
        RemoveDoubletItems(FooList);


       //Still 15 records - why? It should pass by refernce right? 
       //and show 14 - But its not !    

        MessageBox.Show(FooList.Count().ToString());

    }

    private void RemoveDoubletItems(List<MyTable> FooList)
    {
        var remList = new List<MyTable>();

           remList.Add(FooList.First());//Just an example

           FooList = FooList.Except(remList).ToList();

       //Shows 14 
        MessageBox.Show(FooList.Count().ToString())
    }
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing 2 things here.

It is not passed by reference. Actually both the instances are pointing to same reference.

In the first example you are modifying the same reference so you see the change in your original list whereas in your second example you are assigning a new reference here

```
FooList = FooList.Except(remList).ToList();
```

Which means that now FooList is not pointing to a reference it was pointing earlier. therefore you are not seeing the impact in your original list. You can see what you are doing the below image.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you - i can breathe again ! :) its creating a new object ! When i use toList().

Comment: Thanks for the schematics, well explained!

Answer (score 3):

`FooList.Except(remList).ToList();` creates new list - it does not modify the source collection.

In `foo` method you have local `FooList` variable, which is pointing to `List<MyTable>` instance.

You're passing the same reference to `RemoveDoubledItems` and assign it to another local `FooList` variable.

Then, you're creating new `List<MyTable>` (using `Except().ToList()`) and change local `FooList` variable to point to that new list. However, the `FooList` from `foo` method still points to the initial list! That's why `Count` returns 15.

Comment: @Niklas `FooList` is a local variable, after you point it to new `List<T>` it has nothing to do with `FooList` from `foo` method. See my updated answer.

Comment: @marcinjuraszek is correct, you can check here...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx